# Change value of DataFrame rows that are in other DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the values of the ros of a DataFrame that are contained in another DataFrame column/Series.

I have 2 DataFrames:

1. means:

```py
means.columns = Index(['Date', 'a_min', 'a_cierre', 'a_max',
                       'b_min', 'b_cierre', 'b_max', 'conj'], dtype='object')
```

2. pai:

```py
pai.columns = Index(['mes', 'direccion', 'accion', 'min', 'cierre', 'max', 'Date'],
                    dtype='object')
```

And the next code works well for my problem:

```py
for x in pai.Date:
    means[means.Date==x] = 9999
```

But I want to write this in one line only.

Comment: `means.loc[means.Date.isin(pai.Date),'column_to_write']=9999` ?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!